# How do to log a Error Callback in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I am trying to connect to a database using the code below:

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'

var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "banco.db", createFromLocation : 1}, this.successCB(), this.errorCB());

errorCB() {
  this.setState({message: "I NEED SHOW THE ERROR HERE"});
} 

successCB() {
  this.setState({message: "SQL executed fine"});
}
```

How to show the error on the `errorCB` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in [the documentation example](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#step-3-write-application-javascript-code-using-the-sqlite-plugin). The error callback will get passed an argument containing the error. You are also not providing the correct value to `openDatabase`. You should be passing in functions, not trying to call the function.

Copy pasting the relevant parts from the documentation with comments to explain:

```
// Your error callback function that should take an argument that will contain your error.
errorCB(err) {
  console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
  // Here you can use err in your setState call.
}

openCB() {
  console.log("Database OPENED");
}

// openDatabase should be passed in the functions; openCB and errorCB in this example.
var db = SQLite.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "Test Database", 200000, openCB, errorCB);

// What you're doing is incorrect as it's akin to doing this which is wrong.
// var db = SQLite.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "Test Database", 200000, openCB(), errorCB());
```

This is really more of a basic JavaScript question where you need to be able to read the documentation and understand how to use a given API. If you're having trouble with this, I suggest reading up about [Higher-Order Functions](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) as it's fundamental to JavaScript.

**Edit:** To be very direct and answer the comments; this is what your code should look like:

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'

var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "banco.db", createFromLocation : 1}, this.successCB, this.errorCB);

// Making the assumption that these are in a class,
// otherwise add the const keyword before them.
// Convert these to arrow functions instead
// so they can more easily be passed as variables.
errorCB = (err) => {
  this.setState({message: err});
}

successCB = () => {
  this.setState({message: "SQL executed fine"});
}
```

Given your comments, I'll be very direct here. If you don't understand how functions, Higher-Order Functions, and variables/values work in JavaScript, you are going to have a very difficult time with React Native. Especially so if you are unfamiliar with ES6 syntax. Go through the book in that link or one of the many other great resources for learning the fundamentals of JavaScript before tackling React Native.

Comment: the `openCB` and `errorCB` are not variables, so I receive a error when I use it

Comment: and I dont wont to write my custom error, I want to get the error of the database

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo I've added the exact code you should be using. You should really go through JavaScript fundamentals as using functions as variables is a core concept of writing JavaScript. It is especially important in React Native where a lot of it is pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I used to open SQLite using following statement

```
database = SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'}, (db) => {
     db.transaction( tx => {
     tx.executeSql(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (columnNames)`);
        }, error => {
           this.setState({message: error});
     });
 }, error => {
    this.setState({message: error});
});
```

Hope this will help!